# Can I validly expand the odds ratio analogously to the relationship between relative risk & the incidence rate ratio?

Tags: epidemiology, nested-data, case-control-study

I am involved in a nested Case-Control study that involves cohorts of cases and controls entering a program, with the outcome of failure by six months.  Cases and controls are individually matched on month / year of entry.  I have a lot (>10,000) of both.

A primary risk factor of interest is receiving a medical diagnosis (psychiatric, musculoskeletal, respiratory) after entry and before 6 months.  I have the person-time at risk for cases and controls to develop this risk factor, and can directly measure the incidence density of onset of risk factor in each cohort.

**Now, for background:**

The relative risk (RR) is defined as:
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{N_\text{Cases exposed}}{N_\text{population exposed}}\right)}{\left(\frac{N_\text{cases unexposed}}{N_\text{population unexposed}}\right)}.
$$
The incidence rate ratio (IRR)  is defined as:
$$
\frac{{\left(\frac{N_\text{Cases exposed}}{\text{Person-time exposed}}\right)}}{\left(\frac{N_\text{cases unexposed}}{\text{Person-time unexposed}}\right)}.
$$
The odds ratio (OR) is defined as:
$$
\frac{N_\text{cases exposed}*N_\text{controls unexposed}}{N_\text{controls exposed}*N_\text{cases unexposed}}.
$$
Under the rare disease assumption the OR approximates the RR.

**My Questions:**

Can I validly expand on the odds ratio using person-time:
$$
\frac{N_\text{cases exposed}*\text{Person-time unexposed}}{N_\text{controls exposed}*\text{Person-time exposed}}
$$

- to approximate the IRR?
- If not, why not, and what alternative would you suggest?
- If I can do this, would logistic regression would be appropriate?
- What other analytic approaches would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

This link provides a decent discussion of this: https://www.ctspedia.org/do/view/CTSpedia/SampleIncidence

Your answer is yes, conditionally. If you are using incidence density sampling (that is that controls are sampled from the risk set each time a case is diagnosed) which effectively matches cases and controls for time at risk, you are indeed estimating the incidence rate ratio. [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18794220) might also be of interest.

Yes, if you can do this, logistic regression would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your approach would give a valid $IRR$ approximation. First, you would be "looking into the future" to determine the person-time at risk through this approach, since you know cases/controls. Generally speaking, looking into the future like that causes all sorts of problems. Second, there is a stipulation to the rare-disease assumption, and that is that every strata is rare (generally defined as 10%). That means each strata of month/year (along with any other variables you stratify by) would need to satisfy the assumption. Third, if the rare-disease assumption is met, then the $RR$ will approximate the $IRR$ following from $RR \le IRR \le OR$ when $RR \ge 1$.

Instead of the above approach, I would recommend revising the control selection procedure since you have a nested case-control study. Depending on how controls are selected, the case-control $OR$ (abbreviated $ccOR$ hereafter) can approximate different cohort measures. There are three approaches I will briefly detail; case-cohort, density, and cumulative control sampling. (*note:* case-cohort and density sampling require careful determination of what the start time is)

For case-cohort sampling, controls are sampled from baseline of the cohort study *irrespective of later case status*. Under this scenario $ccOR$ is the cohort $RR$

For density sampling (this is the one you will want to use), controls are selected at every time point when a case occurs, *irrespective of later case status*. As an example, consider case-1 occurs at $t=0.5$. From *all* individuals who are *not* cases at $t \le 5$, you randomly select a control from that group. In this way, the control selection mimics person-time in the cohort study, and $ccOR$ approximates the $IRR$

Lastly, is cumulative sampling where controls are selected at the final follow-up time, where controls cannot be cases. In this scenario, the $ccOR$ approximates the cohort $OR$, which under the rare disease assumption the cohort $OR$ approximates the cohort $RR$

Finally, based on the matching procedure you would need to use conditional logistic regression. However, I would forgo matching since it will not necessarily improve efficiency and you will still need to include the matching criteria in your regression model despite matching. I would skip matching and directly include month/year of entry in the conditional logistic model

**Sources / Further Reading**

Case-control selection: 
*Modern Epidemiology* 3rd Edition pg 121-126

Matching in case-control: 
[Pearce 2016](https://www.bmj.com/content/352/bmj.i969),
[Mansournia 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29101596)